# Trying to separate my SendGrid html email templates on my node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

I'm running a node server and I'm sending emails with SendGrid. I need to separate my email HTMLs from my js files so I can modify them from a single base. What I have now is this:

```
const express = require('express')
const config = require('config')
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
const sendKey = config.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY')
sgMail.setApiKey(sendKey)

  const msg = {
    to: "test@test.com",
    from: "test@test.com",
    subject: 'Welcome To The App',
    text: 'Text is here',
    html: <strong>HTML HERE</strong>
  }

  sgMail.send(msg)
```

I want to call my HTML property outside of my current js file instead of writing HTML inside my msg object.

How can I have a separate welcomeEmail.html file and add it to my msg object in my js file?

I've tried fs module but all I have is

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './welcomeEmail.html'
```

I couldn't be able to read my HTML file anyway.

Any idea of what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can** use `fs`, you probably have read from wrong path.

Use this:

```
fs.readFile('./welcomeEmail.html', 'utf8', (err, content)=>{//do Something});
```

Make sure `welcomeEmail.html` is in the right place in your project.

Please remember `readFile` is `async` so you should do the rest of your code in the callback, so your code should be something like this (depends on what is the use case):

```
const express = require('express')
const config = require('config')
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
const sendKey = config.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY')
const fs = require('fs')
sgMail.setApiKey(sendKey)


fs.readFile('./welcomeEmail.html', 'utf8', (err, content)=>{

  if(err){
      console.log(err);
  }
  else{
      let msg = {
        to: "test@test.com",
        from: "test@test.com",
        subject: 'Welcome To The App',
        text: 'Text is here',
        html: content
      }

      sgMail.send(msg)
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now I don't have any errors but I'm not able to render my welcomeEmail.html. I tried as a whole HTML file with the HTML boilerplate and everything and also just as a single HTML element like <strong>Welcome to the APP</strong>. content returns undefined no matter what

Comment: @baranobek what do you mean by not able to render? Does it succeeded to read the content of the file? Can you debug and tell me what's in `content`?

Comment: When I console log the content it's undefined. I don't have any "no such file" error, so probably my file routing is correct now. I changed my html file from a full html file to a single html tag, tried both but the result is undefined both cases            
    fs.readFile('./welcomeEmail.html', 'utf8', (err, content) => {
            console.log(content)
          }) console logs undefined

Comment: This works for me actually.. Umm.. I've edited the answer with the `require` of `fs` (`const fs = require('fs')`) have you been doing it as well?

Comment: Aha I've solved it! I was still having routing problem but I couldn't see. I've console logged err and it told me that it still can not find the HTML file. Then I realized my running js file is inside a folder and for fs ./welcomeEmail.html doesn't mean the current directory. It's actually the root directory. So I've changed it as ./routes/welcomeEmail.html and it worked. Thank you very much I've been trying to solve this for about 4 hours now:) much appreciated

Comment: You're welcome! happy coding :)
Editing with your notes.

Comment: Hi if the answer, or another answer, solved your problem, you can accept it so others can find the solution if they will meet the same situation. :) See also How does accepting an answer work: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/785217